# Angular: member variable undefined within function

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have the following service, which has a function that returns an Observable, since it takes data from another service, transforms it and then returns it (as an Observable).

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ReportColumnHeaderService {

  constructor(private companyService: CompanyService) {}

  public getColumnHeaderElements(variableDimensions: string[]): Observable<HeaderElement[]> {

    return Observable.create(function(observer) {

      this.companyService.getCompanies( (companies: Company[]) => {
        let headerElements = getHeaderElements(companies);
        observer.next(headerElements);
        observer.complete();
      });

    });

  }
}
```

The problem is that `this.companyService` is undefined within the `function`. I read that it should possible if I use an `=>` like that:

```
return Observable.create((observer)  => {

   this.companyService.getCompanies( (companies: Company[]) => {
   let headerElements = let headerElements = getHeaderElements(companies);
   observer.next(headerElements);
   observer.complete();
  });

});
```

But that code does not compile. It says `Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.` Can someone give me a hint how to solve the problem?

Comment: *"It says Expected 0 arguments, but got 1."* What says that? Where? In relation to what specific line?

Comment: Your fundamental edit (changing to an arrow function) is correct.

Comment: The compiler error refers to the line ``this.companyService.getCompanies( (companies: Company[]) => {``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `getCompanies` returns an observable, you are missing `subscribe` on the funtion. The correct call is given below:

```
this.companyService.getCompanies().subscribe( (companies: Company[]) => {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  this.companyService.getCompanies( (companies: Company[]) => {
        let headerElements = getHeaderElements(companies);
        observer.next(headerElements);
        observer.complete();
      });
```

if you want get data from service, you need to use subscribe. The best aproch would be create your constant in method or public variable. For example

```
companies: Company[];


this.companyService.getCompanies.subscribe((res) => {
                this.companies = res;
                console.log(this.compmanies)
                /** this is just simple exemple */            
              });
```

**Subscribing to observables**
Remember, observables are lazy. If you don’t subscribe nothing is going to happen. It’s good to know that when you subscribe to an observer, each call of subscribe() will trigger it’s own independent execution for that given observer. Subscribe calls are not shared among multiple subscribers to the same observable.
https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-creating-and-subscribing-to-observables-in-angular-426dbf0b04a3

And of course if you create subscribe, do not forgot to unsubscribe.